# Replacing chars from string

Tags: c++, character-encoding, mfc

My code is the following (reduced):

**CComVariant* input** is an input parameter

```
    CString cstrPath(input ->bstrVal);    
    const CHAR cInvalidChars[] = {"/*&#^°\"§$[]?´`\';|\0"};
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(cInvalidChars); i++)
    {
       cstrPath.Replace(cInvalidChars[i],_T(''));
    }
```

When debugging, value of cstrPath is L"§", value of cInvalidChars[7] is -89 '§'

I have tried to use .Remove() before, but the problem remains the same: when it comes to § or ´, the code table does not seem to match and the char does not get recognized properly and will not be removed. using a TCHAR array for invalidChars results in even different problems ('§' -> 'ﾴ').
The problem seems that I am not using the correct code tables, but everything I tried so far did not result in any success.
I want to successfully replace/delete any occuring '§'..

I also have had a look at several "delete character from string"-Posts but I did not find anything that helped me.

executable code:

```
CComVariant* pccovaValue = new CComVariant();
pccovaValue->bstrVal = L"§§";

const CHAR cInvalidChars[] = {"§"};
CString cstrPath(pccovaValue->bstrVal);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(cInvalidChars); i++)
{
    cstrPath.Remove(cInvalidChars[i]);
}

cstrPath = cstrPath;
```

just break into **cstrPath = cstrPath;**

Comment: It would probably best if you could create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/), that is a block of code people can take, feed their compiler and see for themselves what is happening. We don't know what the code around it does, how it influences things, and what the variables are that you use, but are declared/defined outside of what we can see.

Comment: @PlasmaHH ok, i will create a mock-piece of code. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: You need to try to understand whether your application targets Unicode or not. The fact that you use `_T()` suggests that you think that you might still need to support Windows 98. Perhaps you should move on from supporting Windows 98 and embrace Unicode. Do be clear that some of your characters have no ASCII representation. Your use of `strlen()` is also something of a travesty. That will return a result that you don't expect, due to the embedded null-terminator. Why are you coding in C++ and calling `strlen()`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sorry, the _T('') was a dirty workaround to try Replace instead if remove. however, strlen does not mutate the cInvalidChars and the loop does not seem to be the problem. Sorry, this code is inherited and I am not a c++ expert, especially not when it comes to string processing..

Comment: Well, I guess I cannot help you if you don't believe what I say, or heed what I say. I say that `strlen()` is wrong. You say it is fine. I say that you need to get on top of the character encoding, you ignore those points. At which point, I can help no further.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan maybe i misunderstood you - but i am only using strlen() to iterate through the array - am i wrong? - the problem persists with "for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 1; i++)" for the current example.. and sorry, I did not mean to be rude.

Comment: You still fail to address the issue of character encoding. Maybe that because you don't know about it yet. Do you know anything about that subject?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i guess not enough, but that seems to be the problem. my debug values look like this, too (negative values for code tables?)

Comment: At the very least you have to try to understand whether or not you target Unicode. You cannot continue until you know what encoding you are using. Is `CString` `CStringW` or `CStringA`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it was CStringW and has to be CStringA.. that's the problem. If you could point out the problem as an answer, i will accept it. Thank you very much for your hint.

Comment: Well, I don't think that's the right solution. You should be using Unicode not ANSI. I'll write that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments you are mixing up Unicode and ANSI encodings. It seems that your application is targeting Unicode which is good. You should stop using ANSI altogether.

Declare `cInvalidChars` like this:

```
CString cInvalidChars = L"/*&#^°\"§$[]?´`\';|";
```

The use of the `L` prefix means that the string literal is a wide character UTF-16 literal.

Then your loop can look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cInvalidChars.GetLength(); i++)
    cstrPath.Remove(cInvalidChars[i]);
```